# How to create a query from three tables for a detailed client statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get a detailed statement of account for a particular client drawn from three different tables of buildings and presented in one report. 
I use stored procedures

```
 customers table
 id_customer    name 
 -------------------------------
 1              tom
 2              sam

orders table

no   customer_id  amount    date
------------------------------------------
1    2            150       1-1-2018
2    1            45        1-1-2018
3    2            25        3-1-2018


receipt table

no   id_customer   amount   date 
-----------------------------------------
1    1             75       1-1-2018
2    2             100      2-1-2018
```

I want the result to be like this

```
  Operation type  reference_no   description   Debit  Credit Balance  date
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  order           1              .....         150     0     150    1-1-2018
  receipt         2              cash          0       100   50     2-1-2018
  order           3              .....         25      0     75     3-1-2018
```

when the customer_id = 2

Comment: your table should contains some date to order with right?

Comment: Yes there is but I did not include it

Comment: the date should be used in order to know that receipt 100 should comes after order 150 and not at the end, you might need to update your question to include this important information

Comment: okay I'll .......................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

1. create a view to store the following `(type,id,debit,credit,date,description)`
2. run the query that will update each row with the `sum  of previous records` and adding the `debit - credit` of the current row

**The view code**

```
create view result as
   select type = 'order',
          id,
          id_customer,
          debit = amount,
          credit = 0,
          [date] = order_date,
          [description]='....'
   from orders
   union all
   select type ='receipt',
          id,
          id_customer,
          debit = 0,
          credit = amount,
          [date] = receipt_date,
          [description] ='cash'
    from receipts
```

**The query**

```
declare @id_customer int = 2
;with initial as(
  select *
  from result
  where id_customer= @id_customer
),report as(
  select r.id,[balance]=isnull((select sum(b.debit-b.credit)
               from initial b
               where b.[date]<r.[date]) + r.debit - r.credit ,r.debit-r.credit)
  from initial r
)

 select [Operation type] = type,
        reference_no = r.id,
        [description],
        [Debit] = debit,
        [Credit] = credit,
        [Balance] = b.balance
 from result r
 inner join report b on b.id = r.id
 where r.id_customer = @id_customer
 order by r.[date]
```

**The result**

Here a working [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29a91/2)

```
Operation type  reference_no    description Debit   Credit  Balance date
order                   1              ....       150      0    150     2018-01-01
receipt                 2              cash        0       100  50      2018-01-02
order                   3              ....        25      0     75     2018-01-03
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I used `@id_customer` as a variable for the explanation purpose, this variable can be replaced by a value like `2` which used in your question or you can create a procedure that takes the `@id_customer` as parameter. you can change the usage of `@id_customer` based on your context usage

Comment: it seems your question is not complete because there are some scenarios not covered, that is why you are not getting the desired result, kindly based on the result you got, can you edit your question to add more information? because the query I wrote was based on your question's details and it works.

Comment: sir Can you add a column that looks like automatic numbering so that the value is unique

Comment: yes you can, either adding a columns with `identity(1,1)` to your table or to use `row_number()`

Answer (score 0):

```
  Create table #customers (id_customer int,name varchar(10))
Insert into #customers values (1,'tom'),(2,'sam')
Create table #orders(no# int,customer_id int,amount int,dtupdt date)
Insert into #orders values(1,2,150,'1-1-2018'),(2,1,45,'1-1-2018'),(3,2,25,'3-1-2018')
Create table #receipt (no# int,id_customer int,amount int,dtupdt date)
Insert into #receipt values (1,1,75,'1-1-2018'),(2,2,100,'2-1-2018')

Select customer_id,row_number()over(order by dtupdt) as RefNo ,ordertype,
Case when ordertype='Receipt' then 'Cash' else '' end as Description,
credit,debit,
sum((case when credit=0 then debit when debit=0 then -credit else 0 end))over (order by dtupdt) as balance,
dtupdt
 from (
select *, case when ordertype='Orders' then tbl.amount else 0 end as debit, 
case when ordertype='Receipt' then tbl.amount else 0 end as Credit from #customers cst
inner join
(
select 'Orders' as ordertype,* from #orders where customer_id=2
union 
select 'Receipt',* from #receipt
where id_customer=2
)tbl
on cst.id_customer=tbl.customer_id
)tbl1
order by dtupdt
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near 'tbl1'

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

Declaration of tables

```
declare @customers table(id_customer int, name varchar(10))
insert into @customers values (1,'tom'),(2,'sam')
declare @orders table([no] int, customer_id int, amount int, [date] date)
insert into @orders values (1,2,150,'1-1-2018'),(2,1,45,'1-1-2018'),(3,2,25,'3-1-2018')
declare @receipt table([no] int, id_customer int, amount int, [date] date)
insert into @receipt values (1,1,75,'1-1-2018'),(2,2,100,'2-1-2018')
```

Actual query:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) as ReferenceNo, OperationType, [Description], Debit, Credit,
       SUM(Debit) over (order by [date] rows between unbounded preceding and current row)-SUM(Credit) over (order by [date] rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Balance,
       [Date]
from (
    select O.OperationType,
           case when O.OperationType = 'receipt' then 'Cash' else '...' end [Description],
           case when O.OperationType = 'receipt' then 0 else O.amount end [Debit],
           case when O.OperationType = 'order' then 0 else O.amount end [Credit],
           O.[date]
    from @customers as C join (
        select *, 'order' as OperationType from @orders
        union all
        select *, 'receipt' from @receipt) as O
    on C.id_customer = O.customer_id
    where O.customer_id = 2
) as a
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'rows'.
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 10
Must declare the table variable "@customers".
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 11
Must declare the table variable "@orders".
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 13
Must declare the table variable "@receipt".